# non-linear ODE method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system which I am trying to solve.

$$
(1) \qquad x' = ax(1-x) + b (1-x)^2
$$

The solution is:

$$
x(t) = \frac{e^{at}-1}{e^{at}-1 +(a/b)}
$$

My method is to first multiply out the brackets in (1) to obtain:

$$
x' = ax -ax^2 + b + 2bx + bx^2
$$

This is not separable so can't be directly integrated. I then collect like powers.

$$
x ' = (b-2a) x^2 + (a+2b)x + b 
$$

I was trying to get it into a Bernoulli form apart from the $b$ term on the end! I do not know where to proceed from here.

Comment: The equation $(1)$ is separable. Divide by the RHS and use partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=y+\lambda$ then with substitution in
$$x ' = (b-2a) x^2 + (a+2b)x + b$$
we have
\begin{align}
y ' 
&= (b-2a) (y-\lambda)^2 + (a+2b)(y-\lambda) + b\\
&= (b-2a) y^2 + y(2\lambda(b-2a)+(a+2b))+((b-2a)\lambda^2+(a+2b)\lambda + b)
\end{align}
determine $\lambda$ such that $(b-2a)\lambda^2+(a+2b)\lambda + b=0$, then you have the Bernoulli equation
$$y'-sy=(b-2a)y^2$$
where $s=\pm\sqrt{a^2+12ab}$.